# Qt5: could not connect signal to slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to upgrade my old Application.. (add it one more function). So, I added one more item in 'File' menu.

```
<addaction name="actionDownload_Firmware_Image"/>

<action name="actionDownload_Firmware_Image">


<property name="text">
    <string>&amp;Download Firmware Image</string>
   </property>
   <property name="menuRole">
    <enum>QAction::ApplicationSpecificRole</enum>
   </property>
  </action>
```

Defined my Slot here:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionDownload_Firmware_Image_triggered()
```

MainWindow.h>

```
private slots:
    void on_actionDownload_Firmware_Image_triggered();
```

So, I clean my project, `run qmake`, build project... Play it, and I get exactly the same GUI as before, no new Menu item.

When App is run, I get the following message>

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionDownload_Firmware_Image_triggered()
```

I noticed on other questions on stackoverflow that `connectSlotsByName` is not recommended for use, but all of my functions and slots are called exactly the same, so it should work like this.

I'm not sure why this is happening, any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add your action by using the designer or did you just edit the .ui file with a text editor?

Comment: I used the designer to edit .ui

Comment: Now I tried just changing the text of About item in one of the menus and that didn't change after build.

Comment: It is a typical error. Try to add `Q_OBJECT` macro in your `MainWindow` declaration. And next time provide an SSCCE with your problem (not only several lines from class defination).

Comment: I already have 
'class MainWindow : public QMainWindow'
'{'
    'Q_OBJECT'

Also, what could be SSCCE in this case, I can't post a few thousand lines of code, and this is the way to post the important ones.

Comment: Did you copy paste it right? I don't recall any `<addaction>` tags.

Comment: Check if the `ui_mainwindow.h` file is removed when you clean your project. If it's not, remove it manually, then rebuild your project,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved!

No coding was needed...

While compiling, Qt puts the `ui_mainwindow.h` in its newly created build folder, and not in the project folder.. So the app doesn't see the updated .h

After copying new .h to the project folder, doing `qmake` and building again, everything looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the underscores in the action name. And define the slot as:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionDownloadFirmwareImage_triggered(bool checked)
```

Comment: You need also to change the slot signature, add `bool checked`.

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. Can you please explain why this should help in any way?

Comment: `connectSlotsByName()` tries to match `void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>)`, note the parameters of `QAction::triggered(book checked)` signal.